# Setting datasourceStrategy as preferAppLevel is not taking into consideration

Tags: jss

My understanding is that if we set `datasourceStrategy="preferAppLevel"` when we open a route with Sitecore Experience Editor and we want to add a component the data source location should be in Components folder at app level (`appDatasourcesPath="$sitecorePath/Components"`) but for us it takes the route level folder so it seems that updating config from preferRouteLevel to preferAppLevel has no effect.

We are using Sitecore 9.2 and JSS 12.

Answer (score 1):

The data source strategy is used during the import process to determine the allowed data source locations for any created renderings. It is not working as you've thought. To achieve what you are describing you would need to change renderings data source location.

For more information's take a look here: [Import Datasource Location Strategies](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/app-import#import-datasource-location-strategies).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But anyway If i set Datasource Location in a Json Rendering it works only if I had one Route if I add more than one Route, when I try to add a new component based on that rendering  from experience editor it give me a bad Datasource Location like the routes under it in place of the Datasource Location specified on that Json Rendering.